# How to stop add Messages temporarily in ArcGIS Python?

Tags: arcpy, python

I want to stop `arcpy.AddMessages` temporarily

```
class A:
   def somefun(self):
      arcpy.AddMessage("Code Message")
      ***code****
class B:
    def execute (self):
        c=A()
        c.somefun()
```

When I call the `somefun` function its executes and shows messages but I need stop temporarily how?

Comment: Why not comment out the add message code?

Comment: This is more of a Software Engineering 101 issue than a GIS one, and there's half a dozen ways to accomplish this, depending on whether you want to use a global variable or a Boolean parameter, or a function parameter or an object parameter, and whether you want to save unprinted messages or save them to a file, or display them in the progress bar. I've done all of these and more, depending on the needs of the application. It's just a code implementation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add some sort of flag perhaps:

```
class A:
   def somefun(self, quiet=False):
      if not quiet:
          arcpy.AddMessage("Code Message")
      ***code****
class B:
    def execute (self):
        c=A()
        c.somefun(quiet=True)
```